# Why are visas not electronic?

Tags: visas, passports, factoids, e-visas

With our increasing reliance on technology why do we have to carry paper visa 'stamps' in our passport instead of using some electronic system? I am assuming a passport number is linked to a visa so there has to be an electronic record which surely could be utilized?

Comment: Aussies already have electronic visas (only for some nationalities). Probably other nations will follow...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One reason is that not every country has computerised their passport/visa system.  They're coming along, but still.

In addition, not every country's system is linked together.  So even if you scanned it in at one border, you can't tell that's happened at the next.

Crossing into Zambia in 2005, they opened their book to the date, drew in a line for New Zealanders, and literally crossed off 5 lines ( | | | | with a --- through the four vertical lines).

It costs a LOT of money.  Some countries can't afford the investment to get all those systems built, and staff trained to use them.  It's cheaper to hire some chap who can ask questions and cross off lines in a book.

So given all the different computer and paper based systems, the only way to transmit the fact that you have a visa, is to carry a piece of paper - ie, a stamp/visa.

However, it's improving.  With the arrival of those smart passports with chips in them, we now have a common way of having data stored electronically and (mostly) securely.  Next that needs to turn into visas.

New Zealanders arriving home (or visiting Australia) can merely walk to a barrier, scan our chipped passports, get a photo taken and walk through.  British citizens arriving home can have their iris scanned, no stamp required.

So these are slowly changing, but will take time.  In the meanwhile, you get to collect cool stamps! :)

Comment: Electronic visas only work if *all* border crossings of a country are 'online' *all* the time, to be able to check, with a central authority, that the person crossing the border actually has the right to enter the country. But this still requires the existence of a passport that needs to be carried around.

Comment: Well if we could do fingerprint/iris testing then we wouldn't require a passport - a passport is merely a form of identity.

Comment: @MarkMayo Fingerprints and Iris scanning will take awhile but more importantly what if your prints/iris is not in the system?

Comment: Presumably it'd be just like not having a passport now.  If you want to travel now, you get a passport, and when this becomes ubiquitous, you'll get your iris scanned in.  India is already on track to fingerprint and iris scan half its 1.2 Billion population by 2014: http://tv.globalresearch.ca/2012/01/india-fingerprinting-iris-scanning-over-one-billion-people

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yes, but that would require all border crossings in the world to be able to read this information, not just all border crossings of one particular country.

Comment: like I said even in my post - this is still to come.  And it'd only require it for the countries you want to visit.  Say all of Europe had Iris tech, you wouldn't need a passport if you were on the system, unless you were not from Europe, or if you were visiting other countries outside of Europe.  It's certainly something that can develop (and will) over time, in some form.

Comment: British citizens arriving in Britain never get any stamp, in any event. In fact, that's generally true of an EU passport holder travelling to any other EU country.

Comment: Indeed, I should have clarified that last sentence to mean they don't need checking by a passport officer - they can just go through the  Iris.

Comment: +1 Note that visa often require many formalities, taking biometrics could be (and increasingly is) one of them, so countries don't have to rely on other countries deploying this or that technology to use them. If your data aren't in the system, it simply means that you haven't been properly vetted and should be refused entry. That does not solve the off-line border checkpoint problem, though.

Comment: Some countries are having financial problems in providing proper x-ray machines at their airports, do you expect them to provide computerized linked advanced system for passport control? +1

Comment: A printed visa also lets the traveller know their last exit date, and for the police to easily check that the traveller has not overstayed.